# How can I pause execution of a Ruby script and serialize the process to disk?

Tags: ruby, serialization, process, deserialization

One script takes lot of time. I would like to pause it (e.g. by pressing <kbd>p</kbd>) and save it to HDD (e.g. by pressing <kbd>s</kbd>) so I can resume it later from HDD. Libraries like Thread or gems like Celluloid may pause some part of the code, but as far I have seen they cannot save the current process to disk.

Ideally, I would like to put a few lines of codes at the beginning of script or something easy like this.

Comment: So you have a running script and you want to stop it, serialize all of its state to disk, and then restart it from disk later, right?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like this and since there are non-serializable things (open files, sockets, ...) I think there would be significant restrictions if there was anything like this.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

You are solving the wrong problem. If your script takes too long to run, speed up your script rather than try to serialize an OS process.

### Alternative Approaches

If you insist on being able to freeze processes and save state to disk, you may want to consider running your processes inside a virtual machine like VirtualBox or VMware. Both of these products support the ability to pause a virtual machine and save the VM's current state to disk.

I'm unaware of any way to store running OS processes on disk other than inside some sort of virtualization layer. If you really need this functionality, that's the way I'd recommend. However, you'll probably get more bang for your buck by improving the efficiency of your code (profile or benchmark for bottlenecks), scaling up your system, or scaling out your program's tasks in a distributed way.

Comment: Doesn't Smalltalk offer something like this? An image?